# Converting for-loop into -apply function where input is a dataframe not vector

Tags: r, for-loop, tapply

I have a data with 3 columns that approximately looks like this:

```
uid <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
sale <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0)
e <- as.data.frame(cbind(uid, sale))
e$uid <- as.factor(e$uid)
e$sincesale <- NA
```

For each unique id, I want to apply the same procedure - calculate number of days since last sale.

I could easily come up with for-loop that can do this. The problem is that I have millions of rows. So, it takes too much time to finish this procedure. I wanted to use `tapply` on `e$uid`. However, `tapply` only accepts vectors as input.

What alternative (that is faster than for-loop) could be used?

My for-loop:

```
for (i in 2:length(e$uid)){
  #working within the good with the same unique id (uid)
  if (e$uid[i] == e$uid[i-1]){
    if (e$sale[i]==1){
      sincesale[i] <- sincesale[i-1]+1
    }
    if (e$sale[i]==0){
      #if sale just ended, number of days since sale is 1
      if (e$sale[i-1]==1){
        e$sincesale[i] <- 1
      }
      #if sale ended a few periods ago add 1 to previous value of "sincesale"
      if (e$sale[i-1] == 0){
        e$sincesale[i] <- e$sincesale[i-1] + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

UPD:

Okay, I honestly tried working on my own for the last night and morning, but could not come up with the solution to a new problem.I tried using methods suggested but one small issue is that they start calculating "sincesale" from the very first line (because sale==0 is true for the first lines even though sales do not start from the beginning). The following example input generates the results with for-loop ("sincesale") and using suggested dplyr ("sincesale4"):

```
uid <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
sale <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0)
e <- as.data.frame(cbind(uid, sale))
e$uid <- as.factor(e$uid)

   uid sale first sincesale sincesale4
1    1    0     1        NA          0
2    1    0     1        NA          1
3    1    1     0        NA          1
4    1    0     0         1          2
5    1    0     0         2          3
6    1    0     0         3          4
7    2    0     1        NA          0
8    2    1     1        NA          0
9    2    0     0         1          1
10   2    1     0        NA          1
11   3    0     1        NA          0
12   3    0     1        NA          1
13   3    0     0        NA          2
14   3    0     0        NA          3
15   3    0     0        NA          4
16   3    0     0        NA          5
17   3    1     0        NA          5
18   3    1     0        NA          5
19   3    0     0         1          6
20   4    0     1        NA          0
21   4    0     1        NA          1
22   4    0     0        NA          2
```

Comment: Just `e <- data.frame(uid, sale); e$uid <- as.factor(e$uid); e$sincesale <- NA` should sort it I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ave` to look within each `uid` group and get a cumulative sum `cumsum` of the the non-sales days:

```
e$sincesale2 <- ave(!e$sale, e$uid, FUN=cumsum)-1

#  uid sale sincesale sincesale2
#1   1    0        NA          0
#2   1    1        NA          0
#3   1    1        NA          0
#4   1    0         1          1
#5   1    0         2          2
#6   1    0         3          3
#7   2    0        NA          0
#8   2    1        NA          0
#9   2    0         1          1
```

Translating to `data.table` this would be:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(e)
e[, sincesale3 := cumsum(!sale)-1, by=uid]
```

Or `dplyr` with a hat-tip to @RonakShah:

```
library(dplyr)
e %>%
  group_by(uid) %>%
  mutate(sincesale4 = cumsum(!sale)-1)
```